# easy_install opens editor instead of running

Tags: python, easy-install

When I run easy_install in the command line in Windows 7, it opens up my Sublime Text editor instead of actually running the program. In Sublime Text, it just displays the easy_install.py source code.

I tried typing "easy_install" by itself as well as "easy_install virtualenv".

I tried changing the path variable but it still doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: why aren't you using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely occurring because Sublime Text has taken over the file association of .py files.  You will need to reassign the appropriate handler for .py files.  See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859) Microsoft KB on how to change the associated program responsible for handling .py files.  You can also list/modify file associations from the command line using the [assoc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490865.aspx) command.